# Does anybody know how to get to the new Firefox 15 Javascript debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

My Firefox automatically updated today to version 15.  There is now a built in javascript debugger.

Can somebody point me to a useful page that explains how to get to it and optionally how to use it?

I have firebug installed - does that override it?

I have found something that says CTRL-SHIFT-S is the short cut key for it, but this seemingly does nothing.

If, like firebug, I need to set a breakpoint, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look [here](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/15.0/releasenotes/) at the bottom of the page at the unresolved issues... Page reload does not start the debugger...

Comment: In that case - it isn't a replacement for firebug yet, though I still can't even set a break point.  I think I'll wait till the next release, when they've fixed a few things.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Tools / Web Developer` and the `Debugger` for example.

Comment: Yes, that's the same as CTRL-SHIFT-S.  It doesn't do anything - the page flickers and that's it.  Though you have popinted me to the right menu option - I already had a plugin called web developer so didn't look there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes firebug seems to remove the source editor, try disabling it shortly then view the source and you should be able to add breakpoints.

Comment: Firebug disabled - firefox restarted, and still no joy